# Windows authentication asking for login and logging in wrong user

Tags: authentication, iis

I am using windows authentication on an intranet that has been duplicated for two different environments with different servers being accessed.  I am using a domain without periods rather than IP so it should log in automatically but it prompts for a login on site 1.  On site 2 it prompts for a login, but regardless of which user logs in, WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name always returns my login which was the very first login rather than the current user.

Here is my configuration:

Anonymous authentication: disabled

Windows authentication: enabled

web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

Why is it prompting for a login and why is one instance logging in properly and the other not?

Answer (score 0):

Made the mistake of setting a user when the application was created.  It is working now.